# How to make GUI form and tools consider to screen pixel?

Tags: powershell

I would like to make form and all the tools can automatically depend on screen pixel. I tried this, It can work only in some resolution, when I execute in high resolution, the form and all the tools are very small. 
Is anyone can give idea?
I also try WindowState=Maximized, but Is it possible to make the tools can still consider of the screen pixel?

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()
function ConvertTo-ScaledPixel
{
    [OutputType([int])]
    param
    (
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'Height',
                   Mandatory = $true,
                   Position = 0)]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'Width',
                   Mandatory = $true,
                   Position = 0)]
    [ValidateNotNull()]
    [System.Windows.Forms.Form]$Form,
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'Width',
               Mandatory = $true,
               Position = 1)]
    [int]$Width,
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'Height',
               Mandatory = $true,
               Position = 1)]
    [int]$Height
)
    switch ($PsCmdlet.ParameterSetName)
    {
        'Height' {

            if ($Form.AutoScaleMode -eq 'Font')
            {           
                return ($Form.CurrentAutoScaleDimensions.Height / 13) * $Height;
            }
            elseif ($Form.AutoScaleMode -eq 'Dpi')
            {
                return ($Form.CurrentAutoScaleDimensions.Height / 96) * $Height;
            }
            else
            {
                return $Height
            }
            break
        }
        'Width' {
            if ($Form.AutoScaleMode -eq 'Font')
            {
                return ($Form.CurrentAutoScaleDimensions.Width / 6) * $Width;
            }
            elseif ($Form.AutoScaleMode -eq 'Dpi')
            {
                return ($Form.CurrentAutoScaleDimensions.Width / 96) * $Width;
            }
            else
            {
                return $Width
            }
            break
        }
    }
}

$Form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form    
$form.AutoSize = $true
$Form.MaximizeBox = $false
$Form.text = ""
$Form.FormBorderStyle = 'FixedDialog'
$Form.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
$Form.BackColor                  = "#ffffff"
$Height = ConvertTo-ScaledPixel -Form $form -Height $form.Height
$width = ConvertTo-ScaledPixel -Form $form -Height $form.Width
#$Form.WindowState                = 'Maximized'
$Form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size($width,$Height)
$Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Segoe UI",13,[System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Regular,[System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit]::Pixel)
$Form.Font = $Font
$Form.SizeGripStyle = 'Hide'

$Label1                          = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Label
$Label1.text                     = "Please select:"
$Label1.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(700,40) 
$label1.AutoSize                 = $true
$Form.Controls.Add($Label1)

$Combo                        = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
$Combo.AutoSize               = $true
$Combo.DropDownStyle          = "DropDownList"
$Combo.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(190,80)
$Combo.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(690,70) 
$Form.Controls.Add($Combo)
$Combo.Items.AddRange(@(Get-ChildItem -Directory ".\").Name)

$SelectedFile= {
#     Write-Host $Combo.SelectedItem
    $files = [collections.arraylist](Get-ChildItem $Combo.SelectedItem -File *.que)
    $checkedListBox.DataSource = $files
    $checkedListBox.DisplayMember = 'Name'
    $ButtonDelete.Visible = $true
    $ButtonDone.Visible = $true
}
$Combo.add_SelectedIndexChanged($SelectedFile)
$Combo.DisplayMember = 'Name'

$checkedListBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.CheckedListbox
$checkedListBox.CheckOnClick = $true
$checkedListBox.Enabled = $true
$checkedListBox.BackColor = "#ffffff"
$checkedListBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(20,40) 
$checkedListBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(585,400) 
$Form.Controls.Add($checkedListBox)

$ButtonDelete = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button 
$ButtonDelete.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(220,440) 
$ButtonDelete.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(80,30)
$ButtonDelete.Text = "Delete" 
$ButtonDelete.BackColor = "#0095d9"
$ButtonDelete.ForeColor = "#ffffff"
$ButtonDelete.FlatStyle = 1
$ButtonDelete.Visible = $false
$ButtonDelete.Add_Click({
$UserResponse = [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Are you sure to delete?","Message" , 4)
    if ($UserResponse -eq "YES" ) 
    {
        $getfile = ($CheckedListBox.CheckedItems).Name
        $getfile | Out-File .\DeleteFile.txt -Force
        $Form.Close()
    } 
    else 
    { 
        #No activity
    }     
    })
$Form.Controls.Add($ButtonDelete) 


$ButtonDone = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button 
$ButtonDone.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(320,440) 
$ButtonDone.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(80,30)
$ButtonDone.Text = "Done"  
$ButtonDone.BackColor               = "#0095d9"
$ButtonDone.ForeColor               = "#ffffff"
$ButtonDone.FlatStyle = 1
$ButtonDone.Add_Click({$Form.Close()})
$ButtonDone.Visible = $false
$Form.Controls.Add($ButtonDone) 

$ButtonRefresh                         = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Button
$ButtonRefresh.BackColor               = "#0095d9"
$ButtonRefresh.ForeColor               = "#ffffff"
$ButtonRefresh.text                    = "Refresh"
$ButtonRefresh.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(750,440)
$ButtonRefresh.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(80,30)
$ButtonRefresh.Add_Click({
    # Remove all items from the ComboBox
    $Combo.Items.Clear()
    # Repopulate the ComboBox, just like when it was created
    $Combo.Items.AddRange(@(Get-ChildItem -Directory ".\").Name)

})
$ButtonRefresh.FlatStyle = 1
$Form.Controls.Add($ButtonRefresh)

$Groupbox1                       = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Groupbox
$Groupbox1.text                  = "Information:"
$Groupbox1.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(620,480)
$Groupbox1.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(5,5)
$Groupbox1.Padding  = New-Object -TypeName System.Windows.Forms.Padding -ArgumentList (5,5,5,5)
$Form.Controls.Add($Groupbox1)

$Groupbox2                       = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Groupbox
$Groupbox2.text                  = "List:"
$Groupbox2.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(260,480)
$Groupbox2.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(650,5)
$Groupbox2.Padding  = New-Object -TypeName System.Windows.Forms.Padding -ArgumentList (5,5,5,5)
$Form.Controls.Add($Groupbox2)

$Form.Add_Shown({$Form.Activate()})
[void] $Form.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: Looking at the documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.windowstate?view=netframework-4.8 it appears you , as you say, use `$Form.WindowState = 'Maximized'`

Comment: yes, I try `$Form.WindowState = 'Maximized` . But the problem is, how to control the  size of the other tools? like $groupbox or $button? If define the size of those size and location, it will mesh up., and it mean I don't need to use `function ConvertTo-ScaledPixel` anyomore? @Matthew